# Geometry nodes align and randomize (Blender 3.1)

Tags: node-editor, geometry

basically i realized this:

1. I built a mesh
   [image]
2. I distributed an object along a curve and randomized scale and rotation
   [image]
   [image]
3. I then distributed the above result along a rectangular curve
   [image]
   [image]

my problem is:

1. how can I orient the object of fig2 along the "normals" of the small
   sides of the rectangle?
2. how can I randomize each single column?
3. is it possible to do this without using a collection of different
   objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more 'cutting the knot' than directly answering.. it *is* possible to capture the tangents of curves on the points they are converted to, before instancing your flowers on them, but it's quite a tangle.

Is it easier, in this case, to instance your flowers on the sides of a mesh box?

[image]

If you needed to get rid of the 45° at the corners, need stems, or somesuch, that would be more tweaking, but  this seems an easier and more readable starting-point:

[image]

Re: your comment.. challenge accepted.

These nodes added after 'Align to Normal' to give the flowers a slight random twist away from the perfect normal:

[image]

And this cluster added as a branch from the  topless and bottomless box:

[image]

It splits the faces, and then deletes horizontal edges, resulting in vertical edge-segments, flower-to-flower. Those are converted to curves, which are trimmed at both ends to avoid the holes at the centers of the flowers. Then they are converted back to a mesh to give some thickness:

[image]

[image]

My apologies.. this is **Blender 3.1** (stable, at time of writing), because of the *Edge Vertices* node. There will be a getaround, if you really need it, but I think 3.1 is pretty safe to use...

Comment: thanks so much for your help, your solution is elegant, and solves my problem. the meaning of this project remains conceptual. I'd also like to add some threads to simulate the pendants. but for now I am satisfied.

Comment: Hi @zipperzonk! Thanks for the approval! See edit for the kind of tweak that is possible to add threads, etc.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but your level of knowledge on the subject is infinitely higher than mine, I'm just at the beginning. I don't understand where and how to insert the "threads" frame. I seem to guess from your explanation that the threads group acts on the edges of the starting cube.

Comment: @zipperzonk Okydoky.. but I just noticed, one of the nodes is 3.1. Hope that's OK.

Comment: hi @Robin  your work is perfect! i connected according to your example and everything works perfectly. thanks again for your help

Comment: @zipperzonk  Pleasure :)